# Optimization of a recursive algorithm to find nodes matching a certain regex

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, optimization

### The problem

I'm working on a web scraper for reddit posts and I made an algorithm that works. The things is that I find the complexity of the algorithm rather appalling and I'd like to improve it.

I assume that converting this algorithm to something that uses tail recursion would speed up my process, but I'm can't really seem to get it to work.

### What I'm looking for

I'm looking for a guideline or advice on how I can improve it. This of course does not have to be a typed out fix. Just a nod in the right direction would help me a lot!

### High level overview

```
basecase
    if node.null return emptylist
recursivecase
    childvalues := recursion on all the childs of this node
    is current node a match with regex?
        yes -> return this post and child values in an accumulator
        no  -> return child values in an accumulator
```

### Raw Code

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...someregex...")   
private List<String> traverse(CommentNode node) {
    //base case
    if(node == null || node.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
    //recursive case

        //collect all the child values (this is NOT tail recursion)
        Set<String> childValues = new HashSet<>();
        for (CommentNode child : node.getChildren()) {
            List<String> previous = traverse(child);
            childValues.addAll(previous);
        }

        //check if the current node complies with the regex
        boolean matching;
        if(node.getComment().getBody() == null) {
            matching = false;
        } else {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(node.getComment().getBody());
            matching = m.matches();
        }

        //if it is matching, add it to the childvalues so it is
        //properly returned 
        if(matching) {
            if(childValues.isEmpty()) {
                ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                temp.add(node.getComment().getBody());
                return temp;
            } else {
                childValues.add(node.getComment().getBody());
            }
        }

        //cast the set to an array list
        ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        returnList.addAll(childValues);

        //return the values of the children and the current node
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if anything changed with Java 9(pretty sure it didn't) but Java 8 doesn't have tail call optimization.

Comment: Oh.. That might be true indeed. Is there maybe another common optimization that I don't know of then? Or is this the best that I can push this method?

Comment: Tail-call optimisation is more about space than time (although that's not to say it has *no* effect on running time). If your code is much too slow, it won't help all that much.

Comment: Your comment says "if it is matching, add it to the acc", but you don't.  Why don't you just do that instead of copying lists?

Comment: That is indeed confusing! I spent a bit too much time working with Prolog and a sneaky useless accumulator sneaked in. I updated the code to remove the confusion.

Comment: The style of the code in general could ... \*clears throat\* ... be improved a bit. But considering that this question *mainly* seems to be about performance: Did you actually *measure* or benchmark this in any way? Whenever RexEx is involved (particularly, matching them on large strings) I consider this as a likely culprit for a bad performance. To be clear: Are you sure that it does **not** spend most of the time in the `Matcher#matches` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, most probably, you're spending most time in the regex matching and there isn't much you could improve.

Anyway, write a helper method

```
private void collectTo(List<String> result, CommentNode node) ...
```

or maybe a helper class to avoid needless copying. Forget about tail-recursion as it won't give you any substantial speedup. In case the three is very deep, use a queue or a stack to simulate recursion in order to avoid stack overflow.

Simplify you code. Do you want a `Set` or a `List`? In case you drop duplicates, then use `Set` as the result, otherwise use `List` everywhere.

Actually, you need no `childValues` and no `temp` and no `returnList` and nothing but a single collection as the accumulator.

Reuse your `Matcher`. This might help a bit.

The code is far too complicated for what it does.

Look at your regex, maybe it can be optimized. Consider using a different criterion, possibly in addition to the regex.

```
private void collectTo(List<String> result, CommentNode node, Matcher matcher) {
    if (node == null) return;
    String s = node.getComment().getBody();
    if (s != null && matcher.reset(s).matches()) {
         result.add(s);
    }
    for (CommentNode child : node.getChildren()) {
        collectTo(result, child, matcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: I benchmarked the code a bit and it is true that the regex is taking the most time. A speed up (as previously mentioned) will indeed only be found by adding some extra criteria before regex-ing over a comment.